# Hide characters in macro for password control

Tags: vba, excel, passwords

I have created a macro to insert an image, when an individual presses a button on the spreadsheet the below macro will run and a message box will appear for the individual to input a password, if correct the image will be inserted. This works fine but i would like the message box to hide the password with stars e.g. ********

Here is the current Macro:

```
Sub M_Reeve()

'Create the password message box

Dim Answer As String
    Answer = InputBox("Input Operator Stamp Password", "Password")

    If Answer = "Martin" Then

       'Run the copy and paste "Stamp1" macro from module 2

    Stamp1

        'return an error if wrong password

    Else: MsgBox "Wrong password", vbCritical + vbOKCancel, "Incorrect Password"
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't do this in an `InputBox`, but you can in the TextBox in an UserForm! ;)

Comment: Okay, i have created a user from, managed to get it to display text as ****, but i cannot figure out how to link in my macro to it. the current code on the user form is:                                                                            Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
End Sub

Comment: This link should help you : https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/userform_pass_data.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This work for me in Excel 2010 32bit.

Create new Module and Paste this code:

```
Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long, _
ByVal ncode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"GetModuleHandleA" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
(ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As Long, ByVal hmod As Long, _
ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SendDlgItemMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendDlgItemMessageA" _
(ByVal hDlg As Long, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long

'~~> Constants to be used in our API functions
Private Const EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR = &HCC
Private Const WH_CBT = 5
Private Const HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5
Private Const HC_ACTION = 0

Private hHook As Long

Public Function NewProc(ByVal lngCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Dim RetVal
    Dim strClassName As String, lngBuffer As Long

    If lngCode < HC_ACTION Then
        NewProc = CallNextHookEx(hHook, lngCode, wParam, lParam)
        Exit Function
    End If

    strClassName = String$(256, " ")
    lngBuffer = 255

    If lngCode = HCBT_ACTIVATE Then
        RetVal = GetClassName(wParam, strClassName, lngBuffer)
        '~~> Class name of the Inputbox
        If Left$(strClassName, RetVal) = "#32770" Then
            '~~> This changes the edit control so that it display the password character *.
            '~~> You can change the Asc("*") as you please.
            SendDlgItemMessage wParam, &H1324, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, Asc("*"), &H0
        End If
    End If

    '~~> This line will ensure that any other hooks that may be in place are
    '~~> called correctly.
    CallNextHookEx hHook, lngCode, wParam, lParam

End Function

Public Function InputBoxDK(Prompt, Optional Title, Optional Default, Optional XPos, _
Optional YPos, Optional HelpFile, Optional Context) As String
    Dim lngModHwnd As Long, lngThreadID As Long
    lngThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId
    lngModHwnd = GetModuleHandle(vbNullString)
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, AddressOf NewProc, lngModHwnd, lngThreadID)
    InputBoxDK = InputBox(Prompt, Title, Default, XPos, YPos, HelpFile, Context)
    UnhookWindowsHookEx hHook
End Function
```

Then in your code replace `InputBox` with `InputBoxDK`

I found this code in other site in the net and as I remember it was by @Siddharth Rout.